# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Setup Blocked

Tags: ssms

I have installed SQL Server 2018 and want to install the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The followinng problem occcurs during the installation of SSMS.

> Setup Blocked 
>   Something has blocked setup from continuing
>
> Click here for the log file
>
> SSMS can only be upgraded by installing the package of the matching
>   language. Please use the matching version of the installer, or
>   uninstall the current version of SSMS and run SSMS setup again

I have manually deleted files under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools`

and have restarted the computer many times.

The same problem still occurs.

How should I do to solve this problem? Please help me.

Comment: *"I have installed SQL Server 2018"* There is no SQL Server 2018, are you sure you didn't already install SSMS (2018)?

Comment: I installed SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 22):

Open cmd prompt as administrator, copy the below line and RUN:

```
reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32
```

That WORKS FOR ME!!

Comment: It worked for me too, but after the new install I did not have all the files, especially the "ssms.exe" one ... which is a real problem to launch the app :)
So, after a restart of my computer, I launched the install again and made a "repair".
Then I was able to use the app again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this issue when you want to update SSMS then do these steps:

1. Open CMD as administrator and run this command

   ```
   reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32
   ```
2. Restart your PC. It is important to restart your PC otherwise it will not work.
3. Run the setup file again and follow the instruction as usual.

You are done!

Answer (score 1):

The language block is known issue a with the initial SSMS 18.0 GA version. See [this feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37483594/) for possible work-arounds and upvote for visibility.

Comment: Odd that, according to the patch notes, that was "fixed" with the GA release *"The block on mixed languages setup has been lifted. You can, for example, install SSMS German on a French Windows. If the OS language does not match the SSMS language, the user needs to change the language under Tools > Options > International Settings, otherwise SSMS will show the English UI."*

Comment: @Larnu, I think the mentioned fix was actually a different issue with the same symptoms. MS is actively working on the fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl + R or Command Prompt : %temp
2. Open command prompt as administrator and run below command
3. reg DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" /reg:32
4. Run install with administrator rights.
5. If it's not working then restart your pc and try again

Comment: This doesn't seem to be saying much that isn't already said in [@MaHo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72359223/3025856) from a couple of months ago. There's some additional conditions (e.g., only using administrative rights or restarting the computer if the command doesn't work), but the basic guidance is the same. With a bit more reputation, you'll be able to comment on posts to add additional clarifications or considerations. Until then, please don't reiterated posts unless you have a different approach or significantly different explanation.

Answer (score -1):

https://support.threattracksecurity.com/support/solutions/articles/1000070783-msi-error-1618-another-installation-is-already-in-progress-during-installation-uninstallation

I followed the above recommendation. I killed the existing MSIExec.exe and then ran the installation, it worked.